# How to config wordpress ajax timeout limitation

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, timeout

I am working on our own wordpress platform. We are sending a post request to another server and ajax call from that server. If the server response get ready, the page will simply render that response. However, the server will need to process on the data in post request and it may take a long time(more than 1 minute). But for wordpress, I think by default it only allow ajax call for 1 minute. If the time server response comes back exceed one minute, page will get a 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT).

> issue: jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4 POST https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)

I expect to increase upper bound of ajax call limitation. I try to modify timeout-related code in wp-admin folder. Still cant work.

Comment: Firstly do not make cross site requests using ajax, use `wp_remote_post` or `wp_remote_get` instead. Second look into either asynchronous function calls in WordPress or create a scheduled event or something akin to WordPress heartbeat so that you can make rest endpoint on your server which will receive response from the other server, store it in db and check at regular interval if you have received response and perform action in accordance with your need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually in php I am using wp_remote_post right now. But in the frontend, since I want to display the response as soon as receiving the response, I am using an ajax call in javascript. In wp_remote_post method, I already set 'timeout' => 180. But it seems that there is another timeout limitation which decrease it to 60 second. May I have some help?

Comment: This  might be due to other server's timeout setting. If you have any control over there, extend the timeout, or write a recursive function on the endpoint or convert your wp request to send data on small parts and make this work recursively.